# How to replace characters using jquery

Tags: jquery

my text contains ' and " characters so i want replace instead of ' as 1 and " as 2 using jquery

EX:

```
<span style="color: #ff0000; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline line-through">text</span>
```

instead of special characters i want to put 1,2,3,4,etc....
the result will be

```
<span style=1color: #ff0000; font-style: italic; text-decoration: underline line-through1>text</span>
```

Comment: Not sure what you want ... Do you want to remove the quotes ?

Comment: i want to replace (") then the string passed through ajax data to webmethod again in C# code i want to replace the(") for original text

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
var rep = ['\'', '"', '!', '@', '#'];

for (var i = 0; i < rep.length; i++)
{
    str = str.replace(rep[i], ""+(i+1));
}
```

Notice how the index of special characters in array `rep` is utilized while replacing.

Comment: Thanks a lot i used the escape functions..('\'')